# issue with background attachment

Tags: html, css

i had been trying to use background attachment property and the issue that i m facing is that after i use the fixed property, the image in the background gets aligned weirdly ..the image moves to left .. please suggest anything that i can do to avoid this issue ..

Comment: you're more inclined to get some help if you post your markup and CSS

Answer (score 2):

Look into `background-position`. You could add something like:

```
background-position: top center;
```

to keep it fixed to the top and center. You can also specify pixel values.

Comment: is it like i can use this propery only for the body attribute and not the inner divs or elements?/

Comment: @Sachindra, no this property can be applied to any element.

Answer (score 2):

`background-attachment: fixed` will position the background relative to the viewport, rather than the element the background is applied to.

This is the basis for [Eric Meyer's Complex Spiral Demo](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/complexspiral/demo.html). There are more specific details on the linked page.

So, unfortunately, the answer is No. You cannot avoid this behavior and still used `background-attachment: fixed`